# Rebase a git repository

Tags: git, rebase

Previously, there was a branch `version1`.

```
A--B--C--version1 (official repo)
```

I made a new branch `mine` with `version1` as base branch and did some developments.

```
A--B--C--version1--D--E--mine
```

Over time the official repo changed to:

```
A--B--C--version1--X--Y--Z--master
```

How could I rebase my branch to achieve:

```
A--B--C--version1--X--Y--Z--D--E--mine--master
```

Answer (score 0):

Take everything between `version1` and `mine` and put it on top of `master`:

```
git rebase --onto master version1 mine
```

Comment: @Palak Arora, the above command, will result in the below history

A -- B -- C -- X -- Y -- Z -- D -- E 

in branch "mine".  Is that what you are looking for??

Comment: Of course, if you want to include the commits D and E in master too, you can simply fast-forward the master branch to `mine` (`git checkout master; git merge --ff-only mine` or `git push . mine:master`)